# Android | Start Service before MainActiviy starts

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

`onTokenRefresh()` in `FirebaseInstanceIDService`

starts after MainActivity starts. I think this is the reason why `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` sometimes `=null`

How can I start `FirebaseInstanceIDService` before MainActivity starts?

Thanks for your answers, and sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but it won't solve your problem.  Your problem is that talking to the Google server to get an instance id takes time and happens asynchronously.  So even if you start it before onCreate, it may not be finished in time.  The correct solution is to write your code for asynchronous conditions-  don't run any code that requires the instanceID until you have it.  That may mean throwing up a loading screen until the id is available.

Comment: Thats a good idea... But how can i run a loading screen or a loading spinner while a service starts?